# Get unique random number every hour

Tags: c

I was wondering what the best way to get a unique random number every hour in C was. I have integers of hour, month, day of month, and day of week and want to get a random number between 0 and 8 every hour. Initially I tried doing `(hour* month* day_month*week_month)%8` but I think it repeats certain numbers often. Would there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Add this before: 
 srand (time(NULL));

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use a standard cryptographically secure RNG?

Comment: Do you wan't it *securely* random, or just seemingly random?

Comment: i just want the same random number if the calculation is run multiple times within the same hour. i guess as long as it seems random that works

Comment: To make it "random", you could seed `srand` with the product (maybe `hour * d_o_m * month`). Now,  the _first_ `rand()` will give the same number, as the seed is the same.

Comment: Just run as per first comment, and then use `rand`. It will be random enough for you.

Comment: so only the first rand() will be the same? I would like to run it multiple times within an hour to return the same random number

Comment: It won't be the same.

Comment: as long as I run srand again though with the same seed the first rand() will be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to do something like the following:

```
int hourly_random()
{
  srand(time(NULL)/3600);
  return rand() % 8;
}
```

Just simply multiplying non-random integers will not give you something random. Just to illustrate some of the many problems: if one of the values is 0, the result will be 0. If you swap the value of two input variables, the result will still be the same.

This is also the case if you use that result as the seed for a random generator. Because the seed has definite pattern, the resulting random numbers will follow the same pattern.

If you want to use the variables you mentioned, you should combine them such that they don't "interfere" with each other. An obvious way is to multiply the subparts by the maximum value you are adding. That is, something like `hours + 24*(months + 12*(...))`.

When making your own way to generate random numbers, perhaps you should look at how existing random number generators work. That said, in general you really don't want to make such a thing yourself because of all the pitfalls. It's probably better to rely on the work that as already been done before.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reseeding the random number generator each time, you can simply keep track of when the last call was done.  If it was in the same hour, return the same value, otherwise get a new random value.

```
int hourly_random()
{
    static time_t last = 0;
    static int rand_val = 0;
    time_t current;

    current = time(NULL);
    if (!last) {
        srand(current+getpid());
    }
    if ((current/3600) > (last/3600)) {
        last = current;
        rand_val = rand() % 8;
    }
    return rand_val;
}
```